# How to optimise this type of search and replace in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that roughly looks like this

```
ID    VAL 
2     3
2     7
2     4
2     5
2     2
3     4
3     6
3     7
3     2
4     2
4     3
4     4
4     5
4     6
```

Another dataframe that roughly looks like this

```
ID     VAL
2       5
3       7
```

I want to do an operation that for each row in the second dataframe, the row will move to the top.

```
ID    VAL 
2     5
2     3
2     7
2     4
2     2
3     7
3     4
3     6
3     2
4     2
4     3
4     4
4     5
4     6
```

See that the (2, 5) tuple and the (3, 7) tuple have been moved up to where that "ID" begins.

I've currently a horribly inefficient implementation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you care about the rest of the order, e.g. would `2, 5 | 2, 4 | 2, 3 | 2, 7 | ...` meet your requirements?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the order would have to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using a help key create by using `merge` then we `sort_values`

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(key=0),how='left').fillna({'key':1}).sort_values(['ID','key'])
# you can add .drop('key',1) at the end :-)
    ID  VAL  key
3    2    5  0.0
0    2    3  1.0
1    2    7  1.0
2    2    4  1.0
4    2    2  1.0
7    3    7  0.0
5    3    4  1.0
6    3    6  1.0
8    3    2  1.0
9    4    2  1.0
10   4    3  1.0
11   4    4  1.0
12   4    5  1.0
13   4    6  1.0
```